# hide radio button from the spinner selected value

Tags: android

am using spinner in android with the layout  `(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)`
because i need the radio button there , but after i select a value the radio button still showing on the spinner.  is their any way to hide it?

this is my spinner:

```
        <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dip"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:background="@drawable/spin" >

        </Spinner>
```

and this is the activity lines:

```
ArrayAdapter first_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, start_list);
         spinnermo.setAdapter(first_adapter);
```

and this is the spinner after selection:
ooo  i cant dispaly the image but its simmiler to this:

`seleced text (0)`

Answer (score 0):

Using this Code you can hide your spinner.

```
spinnermo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if you want to hide radio button use same code

```
radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thanks mi already got the answer it is to place 2 layout one for the spinner :android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item   and the other ondropdown:android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Answer (score 0):

Yes create two layouts because once you implement ArrayAdapter it will have two methods to be overridded getView and getDropDownView

1. for getDropDownView you have to create a layout with TextView and set corresponding value in it

```html
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/your_own_unique_id_for_checkedtextview"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

2. for getView you have to create a layout with CheckedTextView and call the corresponding method

```html
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/your_own_unique_id_for_textview"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Then in your custom adapter class

override the methods to access the above values respectively

```html
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomCheckedTextView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomTextView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomCheckedTextView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_own_layoutxml_file_name, parent, false);

        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        
        CheckedTextView label        = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.your_own_id_for_checkedtextview);
        // Set values for spinner each row
        label.setText("value");


        return row;
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomTextView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_own_layout_xml_file_name_for_textview, parent, false);

        TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id_name);
        // Set values for spinner each row
        label.setText("value");

        return row;
    }
```